# What is the cost of opening a websocket on each request to a backend server

Tags: php, apache, rest, web, websocket

Due to some job constraints I've been building on top of very ancient applications written years ago for the good *Apache/PHP ssr monolith* combo, and trying to modernize the ecosystem around the business, stabilizing the most I can and improving tooling.

A feature to send notifications to client-side might be needed in the future. I've been doing some research on web sockets due to this constraints and I'm curious for ***What are the implications (performance, stability, reliability, server load) of opening a Web Socket on each request to listen for notifications on the system and if for this to happen I might need to change to a javascript framework like Vue or React to avoid such spamming.***